# keep svninfo package from overwriting \today?

Tags: datetime

I use the package `svninfo` to put the svn revision on my title page so that I know which version people are looking at when they give me feedback. My titlepage also contains the current date though from the command `\today`.

It seems that `svninfo` overwrites that value of `\today` to give me what seems like the date of last check-in or something.

How do I insert the actual current date at compile time independent of any svn date, even when I am using the `svninfo` funtionality elsewhere in my document?

Comment: Could you add a minimal example to play with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/svninfo) mentions the package option `notoday`, which is intended to do what you want.

Comment: How did I even miss that?! Thanks.

Comment: 500 bounty for a one liner.... LOL.

Comment: Sometimes a one liner was exactly what you were looking for ;-)

Comment: @ADP: And _three_ badges (Mortarboard, Nice Answer, Enlightened) so far. `:-)`